# Double for loop in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

There is list named L.
Which contains others list: L=[A,B,C,...N]
I want to for-loop, where B is no equal A (see #2)
Something like: for B is not A in L:

```
for A in L: #1
    for B in L: #2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the rest of the list by index:

```
for i in xrange(len(L)-1):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(L)):
        #L[i] != L[j] always, and will check just one list against the others once
```

Comment: `xrange` doesn't exist in Python 3. Use `range`.

Comment: This will prevent `L[1]` from pairing with `L[0]` (in that order). The OP _seems_ to want to allow `L[0], L[1]` as a pair _and_ `L[1], L[0]` as a pair since the original loop would produce both, and they only wanted to omit `L[x], L[x]` pairings...

Answer (score 0):

Better solution using `itertools`, either [with `permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) or [with `combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

# If it's okay to see L[1], L[2], and later L[2], L[1], that is, order sensitive,
# matching your original question's specification of only avoiding pairing with self:
for A, B in itertools.permutations(L, 2):
    ...

# If you only want to see L[x] paired with L[y] where y > x,
# equivalent to results of Daniel Sanchez's answer:
for A, B in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
    ...
```

Either one of these is significantly faster than using nested loops that require indexing (and bonus, requires only one level of indentation, reducing "arrow patterns" in your code).

If the body of the loop was `print(A, B, sep=',', end=' ')` and `L = [1, 2, 3]`, the output of the `permutations` loop would be:

```
1,2 1,3 2,1 2,3 3,1 3,2
```

For `combinations`, you'd get:

```
1,2 1,3 2,3
```

so choose whichever matches your desired behavior.

An additional benefit of using the `itertools` functions is that they'll work just fine when `L` is a non-sequence collection (e.g. a `set`), or when it's an iterator that can only be traversed once (they'll cache the values internally so they can produce them more than once). Other solutions require explicit conversion to `list`/`tuple` or the like to handle the "`L` is a one-use iterator" case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement to filter out the cases you don't want:

```
for A in L:
    for B in L:
        if A == B:
            continue # skip
        # do stuff ...
```

Comment: That requires an explicit comparison performed `len(L) ** 2` times. And assumes your `list` contains homogeneous (or at least comparable) types. And that equal (but not identity equal) pairings should be rejected (which is not clear), which means weird stuff `L = [1, True]` will produce no outputs at all, while `L = [float('nan')]` will produce an output pairing it with itself. If it can be done in other ways (e.g. `itertools` methods, or failing that, index comparisons, which avoid issues with equality, and edge cases of identity caused by caching), it's better to avoid this "test per loop".